# How to import Affiliate Window data feeds XML in wordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress, dataimporthandler

I need help that I want to import Affiliate Window data feeds XML from this site https://www.affiliatewindow.com to my wordpress website. So kindly assist me how to do this. Kindly help me.

Thanks,
Yousuf

Answer (score 1):

TO add xml feed to your website, look at the code below.

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$feed = fetch_feed( http://uk.affiliatewindow.com/feed/ );
$rss = $feed;
if(!empty($rss)):
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(4);
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
endif;
?> 
<?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo 'No news';
else
foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>

<?php
 // display item title and date  

        echo '<span class="comment_author"><a href="http://uk.affiliatewindow.com/" target="_blank">' . substr($item->get_title(), 0, 65) . '...</a></span><br>'; ?>
        <?
        // if single item, display content
        if(isset($_GET['item']))
        {

            echo ' <span class="latest_content"><a href="http://uk.affiliatewindow.com/" target="_blank">'. substr($item->get_content(), 0, 30).'</a></span>';
        }

        echo '<span class="latest_content">' . shorten($item->get_description(), 150).'</span><br>';

?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In this line `$feed = fetch_feed( http://uk.affiliatewindow.com/feed/ );` is the feed adress
Next i belive you will now!

Here i imported the feed from the site that you want. Look in sidebar for External Feed.
http://5wpthemes.com/press5/

The only thing that you have to do is set href adress!

Tell me if it's work!